# Dynamically load SVGs (or anything) as objects. Chrome security feature?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

The site itself - test.vancebeckett.com  (it's an alpha, I know the text and some other things sucks now, it will be redone).

EDIT:
What's not working (example):
In JS file:

```
var p2ComicTileAttributes = ["class", "comicTiles p2Content", "id", "p2ComicTile", "type", "image/svg+xml", "data", "svg/p2Comic.svg", "onload", "p2Status++;p2Tiles.splice(0,1,this);"];
function loadPageSVGContent(attributesArray) {
    var pageObj = document.createElement("object");
    for (var i = 0; i < attributesArray.length; i += 2) {
        pageObj.setAttribute(attributesArray[i], attributesArray[i + 1]);
    }
    document.getElementById("contentLayout").appendChild(pageObj)
};
loadPageSVGContent(p2ComicTileAttributes);
/*This creates an objects, appends them in DOM, sets thair attributes and even runs thair inline code (onload) in Edge and FF, but do neither in Chrome-based browsers. Is this another Chrome safety feature? Like it can't load SVG's (or any other xml) from another domain and have an access to its DOM, it also doesn't allow do the same from local folder, only from the server. "contentLayout" - div-wrapper in HTML document.
So, maybe there's a way to use ajax and somehow pass loaded document to "data" attribute?
About performance, if I will inject SVG's in the html - these SVG's are 100-200KB each, and I have many. I'm sure it will slow down any DOM manipulations. And also I want to find the best way anyway :).*/
```

What works:
You can check how it works in Edge and FF (maybe somewhere else too) by clicking "Some of my work" and "introduction" in the "Table of contents".

And js file itself for those who couldn't find it and gave a minus in rating: http://test.vancebeckett.com/main.js

(or in FF: Inspect Element - Debugger - main.js)

Comment: An minimal example would be useful.

Comment: Show us main.js

Comment: Why would performance be different? Have you tested that assumption in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved this by myself, finally!
Just use XMLHttpRequest to load .svg file, when it status shows, that it's loaded, create an "object" node with "data" attribute set to "path/to/your/image.svg" and append it to some wrapper in DOM - viola! You have an svg  element which could be animated, and which isn't inline in your html!